# Why is it not possible to add two addresses together?

Tags: c++, pointers, integer-arithmetic

Let's say I've defined two variables `x` and `y`:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
```

I can get the address where `x` is stored via:

```
cout << &x << endl; // 0x61fe18
```

Which is a hexadecimal number. Now, if I want to print this number after adding 5, it is fairly simple:

```
cout << &x + 5 << endl; // 0x61fe1d
```

But if I sum together the addresses of `x` and `y`:

```
cout << &x + &y << endl;
```

I get an error:

> ```
> invalid operands of types 'int*' and 'int*' to binary 'operator+'
> cout << &x + &y << endl;
>         ~~~^~~~
> ```

Why can't I add the two addresses?

Comment: Why would you need to? What would that sum represent? The answer is right in the compiler error message. It's not defined. Because of the answers to my first two questions.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: It is part of an encryption algorithm. I know it is possible to add them, but why not this way?

Comment: Adding addresses together just doesn't make any sense, that's why. What "encryption algorithm" even cares about memory addresses?

Comment: The c++ standard says this nonsense should not compile.

Comment: Also, your compiler error message.

Comment: Addresses are just lies the kernel tells you. They don't have any real meaning outside of very narrow ranges dictated by how they were allocated. With [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and virtual memory these things can be all over the 64-bit address space with no real reason for why.

Comment: My car can go 100 mph.  I'm 170 cm tall.  I can add 100 + 170, and get 270.  What does that **270** mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ability to convert something to an integer does not mean it is an integer.

Computers use binary logic, and you can take any piece of information in binary and convert it to an integer.  But for it to be an integer, it means that addition, subtraction, multiplication and division all have the expected meaning.

Pointers are stored as binary data, but many operations do not make sense on them.

My location on the planet Earth can be represented as a pair of lat/long numbers.  That pair of numbers **is not my location on the planet Earth**.

Adding together numbers is a reasonable operation.  Adding together locations is nonsense.

"Location of NYC" plus "Location of Moscow" does not make sense.

"Latitude of NYC" plus "Latitude of Moscow" is a number, but that number is basically nonsense, and the pair of Lat/Long values of the sum of the Lat/Long values of NYC and Moscow equally so.

The midpoint between NYC and Moscow does make sense, but there are two of them (opposite sides of the world).  Also, 25% of the way between NYC and Moscow makes sense.

Next "the shortest way to get from NYC to Moscow" is a vector.  It isn't a location, but a direction on the surface of the Earth.  You can take that vector and add it to another location -- "what if I started in Toronto instead" -- and get a new location.

Pointers are locations, like "NYC" and "Moscow".  When you add to a pointer, that integer is acting as a *vector* on the space of pointer locations.

C++ attempts to make nonsense operations not happen unless you force it.  Adding pointers -- adding locations -- is nonsense.  Adding an integer to a pointer makes sense.  Taking the difference between two pointers makes sense.

When you print out a pointer, the compiler uses the `void*` overload of `std::ostream& << void*`.  This overload is provided for debugging purposes, and interprets the bits of the pointer as a hexidecimal integer.

You can do this manually by converting your pointer to a `std::uintptr_t` -- an unsigned integer type guaranteed to be large enough to store the bits of a pointer.

---

You'll note that when you do `&x + 5`, the integer you get isn't 5 greater than if you do `&x`.  In fact, it is `&x` + sizeof(x)*5.

This is because pointer arithmetic is assuming you are working on an array, and is moving forward/backwards by one object-size.

```
std::cout << &x << std::endl; // 0x61fe18
std::cout << (&x + 5) << std::endl; // 0x61fe1d
```

that only happens if `x` has `sizeof(x)==1`.  As you claimed `x` was an `int`, that is not possible in C++.

If `sizeof(int)` is `4` (as is common nowadays),

```
std::cout << &x << std::endl; // 0x61fe18
std::cout << (&x + 5) << std::endl; // 0x61fe2c
```

is what you'd get instead.

And this is because, again, pointers are not integers.  The ability to print them as integers does not mean they are integers.

Comment: It is a good explanation, but the domain is quite complicated :) Shortest direction from NYC to Moscow is interesting question, once you take curvature of Earth into consideration, and is not a vector :)

Comment: @SergeyA It is a vector, just not in R^3.  ;)

Comment: I will trust you here. multi-dimensional vectors are beyond my imagination.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, not quite a vector; that was a lie. It is a group element of SO(3).  But regardless, the space of locations on the Earth can have such rotations applied to it in a vector vs affine space like way.

Comment: And even better. )))

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: because C++ standard says so.

Long answer: because it does not make sense. There is never a case when adding two addresses together will yield anything of use.

When you add (or subtract) in integral offset to the address, you arrive to the object which is located at given offset from the address. Very useful and basically a basis of all array operations.

But if you add two addresses together, we arrive at a completely random location in memory, where you can't hope to find anything of value. And thus, language is not allowing you to, and compiler is refusing to compile this code.

However, if you just need a numerical representation of the sum of numerical representation of two addresses (for example, for complicated run-time obfuscation), this can be done using the type which was specially designed for this: `uintptr_t`. Following is a valid code:

```
auto z = uintptr_t(&x) + uintptr_t(&y);
```

Comment: I am not hoping to find something at the new address (which is the sum of the two addresses). I need the numerical value of the sum. Since both are integers, they should be addable this way, as any two integers are.

Comment: @WaisKamal that's a different story altogether. If you need to add two addresses as their numerical representation, this is doable. I will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: They are addresses that **happen** to be represented by integers. Do not think of them as integers.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I know it is doable. My question is why it is not doable *this way*.

Comment: @WaisKamal substraction is defined, it's the distance between two pointers. If you want sum, you have to cast those pointers as ints and then you can add them together. However still nothing usefull

Comment: Why so? The pointers themselves are of integer values (they are not strings, arrays, etc...) so why can't I add them?

Comment: @WaisKamal Why do you need the numerical value of the sum?  Again, pointers are not integers.  You can convert the bits that represent a pointer and ask what the integer with those bits would be, but that doesn't mean that the integer *is* the pointer.  I can convert my location on the earth to Lat/Long values, but my location is not that pair of values.

Comment: @WaisKamal pointers are not integers. They are addresses, and generally follow semantics which are valid for addresses. This is one of the strengths of C++ - it add semantics which are valid for given domain, and thus protects developer from random errors.

Comment: @WaisKamal Pointer types can't be added together because the language doesn't define that addition operator for pointer types. No matter how many times you ask the same question this isn't going to change.

Comment: @WaisKamal Pointers are not integer types. Every implementation has to provide some mechanism for converting a pointer to an integer representation, but pointers themselves are not integer types. Integral types are the variations of `int` (`short`, `int`, `long` and `long long`), the variations of `char` (`char`, `wchar_t`, `char8_t`, `char16_t` and `char16_t`) (and all `signed` and `unsigned` versions) and `bool`, plus the `cv` modified variants. Pointer is not one of those types.